# How can I use the hot reload tool in KivyMD?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I´m learning how to create a simple GUI using KivyMD, but I would like to see real-time changes while working on my app. For some reason, I encounter binding issues when using `from kivymd.tools.hotreload.app import MDApp`, and that's the only way I know how to use hot reload. Those issues are only resolved when I use the standard `from kivymd.app import MDApp`.

This is my **main.app**:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.tools.hotreload.app import m

class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):

        Window.size = (320, 370)
        Window.resizable = 0

        return Builder.load_file("app.kv")

    def check_button_state(self):
        username_text = self.root.ids.username.text
        password_text = self.root.ids.password.text
        quantity_text = self.root.ids.quantity.text

        if username_text and password_text and quantity_text.isdigit() and int(quantity_text) > 0:
            self.root.ids.init_button.disabled = False
        else:
            self.root.ids.init_button.disabled = True

    def get_texts(self):

        user_text_field = self.root.ids.username
        user_text = user_text_field.text

        password_text_field = self.root.ids.password
        password_text = password_text_field.text

        quantity_text_field = self.root.ids.quantity
        quantity_text = quantity_text_field.text

        print(user_text, password_text, quantity_text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

and this is my **app.kv**:

```
FloatLayout: #:kivy !

    Image:
        source: "src/images/instagram_bg.jpg"
        allow_stretch: True
        keep_ratio: False

    MDLabel: 
        text: "Comment Bot"
        color: "#FFFFFF"
        font_size: "38sp"
        font_name: "font.ttf"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.59, "center_y": 0.9}

    MDIcon:
        icon: "instagram"
        color: "#FFFFFF"
        font_size: "45sp"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.85, "center_y": 0.90}

    MDTextField:
        id: username
        line_color_normal: "#ffffff"
        line_color_focus: "#ffffff"
        hint_text: "Nome de usuário ou e-mail"
        size_hint_x: .8
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.725}
        mode: "rectangle"
        hint_text_color_normal: "white"
        hint_text_color_focus: "white"
        text_color_focus: "#ffffff"
        text_color_normal: "#ffffff"
        font_size: "20sp"
        on_text: app.check_button_state()

    MDTextField:
        id: password
        line_color_normal: "#ffffff"
        line_color_focus: "#ffffff"
        text_color: "#ffffff"
        hint_text: "Senha"
        size_hint_x: .8
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.54}
        mode: "rectangle"
        hint_text_color_normal: "white"
        hint_text_color_focus: "white"
        text_color_focus: "#ffffff"
        text_color_normal: "#ffffff"
        font_size: "20sp"
        password: True
        on_text: app.check_button_state()

    MDTextField:
        id: quantity
        color_mode: "primary"
        line_color_normal: "#ffffff"
        line_color_focus: "#ffffff"
        hint_text: "Quantidade de comentários"
        size_hint_x: .8
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.355}
        mode: "rectangle"
        hint_text_color_normal: "white"
        hint_text_color_focus: "white"
        text_color_focus: "#ffffff"
        text_color_normal: "#ffffff"
        font_size: "20sp"
        input_filter: "int"
        on_text: app.check_button_state()

    MDRaisedButton:
        id: init_button
        text: "Iniciar"
        theme_text_color: "Custom"
        text_color: "#FFFFFF"
        font_style: "Button"
        md_bg_color: "#C8439C"
        size_hint: .5, .13
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .155}
        font_size: "16sp"
        on_press: app.get_texts()
        disabled: True
```

I watched some tutorials of people using the ScreenManager tool, but it seems a little complex to me, as I'm just a newbie in this subject. If any of you could tell me how to implement hot reload without encountering any problems with binding functions to buttons, I'll be very grateful.

Thanks in advence.